# subprocess.call halting after showing widget on qt (if shell=True)

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, subprocess

The code below halts on my computer (actually, initially this was failing when I called platform.uname() in the place of the subprocess call, and I narrowed it down to its popen call).

Anyone knows why this happens? (If I use shell=False, it does work, but I'm interested in knowing what's the difference here)

Code halting in subprocess.call in qt3:

```
import qt
import subprocess

app = qt.QApplication([])
q = qt.QWidget()
q.show()
subprocess.call(['doskey'], shell=True)
```

Code halting in subprocess.call in qt4:

```
import subprocess
import PyQt4.QtGui

app = PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication([])
q = PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget()
q.show()
subprocess.call(['doskey'], shell=True)
```

Comment: what happens if you do `subprocess.call('doskey',shell=True)`? (i.e. pass a string, not list).  Passing `list` objects doesn't make a whole lot of sense with `shell=True` I don't think...

Comment: Same thing, it halts (I left it because I was testing putting shell=False too, where it works)

Comment: Also, if I don't call QWidget.show, it works with shell=True too.

Comment: If it works with `shell=False`, why not just use that?  If you need to split arguments into a list intelligently, you could use `shlex.split`.

Comment: What do you mean by "halt"? I've tested your code and works fine on my machine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'halt' and 'fail'?  'hang' and 'crash'?  'raise exception' and 'report a recovered error'?  All `shell` does is control whether the command is called directly (`shell=False`) or provided as an argument to the default cli/terminal program (`shell=True`).  If you see differing results, it could be because the program is not discoverable in one or the other context, or because the calling program is handling an exception differently than a non-0 return code.  What's your system path?

Comment: halt=hang and fail=hang too. My system path does include the file location (doskey is in winows/system32). I've tested in 2 different machines with the same results... Although one thing came to mind: I'm launching the program from 4nt (which is a cmd replacement), so, that could be a reason why it doesn't work -- unfortunately (or not depending how you see it), I'm on vacations today and will only be able to check that again in 3 weeks from now... but 4nt could really be the culprit here.